# unable to start debugging on web server VS2013 WebAPI

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling with this very popular error. I believe I have looked at the related questions and not found one that fits my problem.

I have a visual studio 2013 webapi project that I am trying to run. This code works fine for other team members.
My computer is windows 7, and I haven't previously had any problems running web sites locally.

If I run in debug, I get "Unable to start debugging on the web server"
If I start without debugging I get "{
  "ErrorMessage": "The resource you requested was not found."
}"

**This only happens running as "local IIS". If I select "IISExpress" it runs perfectly well (but on a port).**

I have tried:

- Checking the app pool is .net 4
- Changing the identity of the app pool to my login
- stopping and starting the app pool
- checking the permissions on the local folder
- commenting out all the code in Application_Start of the Global.asax

Any other suggestions would be most welcome

Comment: Did you find the issue. I am facing same issue